# Porting signal windowing code from Matlab to Java

Tags: matlab, voice, optimization

This is part of a code from spectral subtraction algorithm,i'm trying to optimize it for android.please help me.

this is the matlab code:

```
function Seg=segment(signal,W,SP,Window)

% SEGMENT chops a signal to overlapping windowed segments
% A= SEGMENT(X,W,SP,WIN) returns a matrix which its columns are segmented
% and windowed frames of the input one dimentional signal, X. W is the
% number of samples per window, default value W=256. SP is the shift
% percentage, default value SP=0.4. WIN is the window that is multiplied by
% each segment and its length should be W. the default window is hamming
% window.
% 06-Sep-04
% Esfandiar Zavarehei

if nargin<3
    SP=.4;
end
if nargin<2
    W=256;
end
if nargin<4
    Window=hamming(W);
end
Window=Window(:); %make it a column vector

L=length(signal);
SP=fix(W.*SP);
N=fix((L-W)/SP +1); %number of segments

Index=(repmat(1:W,N,1)+repmat((0:(N-1))'*SP,1,W))';
hw=repmat(Window,1,N);
Seg=signal(Index).*hw;
```

and this is our java code for this function:

```
public class MatrixAndSegments 
{
    public int numberOfSegments;
    public double[][] res;

    public MatrixAndSegments(int numberOfSegments,double[][] res)
    {
        this.numberOfSegments = numberOfSegments;
        this.res = res;
    }
}



public MatrixAndSegments segment (double[] signal_in,int samplesPerWindow, double           shiftPercentage, double[] window)
{
    //default shiftPercentage = 0.4
    //default samplesPerWindow = 256  //W
    //default window = hanning 

    int L = signal_in.length;
    shiftPercentage = fix(samplesPerWindow * shiftPercentage); //SP
    int numberOfSegments = fix ( (L - samplesPerWindow)/ shiftPercentage + 1); //N

    double[][] reprowMatrix =  reprowtrans(samplesPerWindow,numberOfSegments);
    double[][] repcolMatrix = repcoltrans(numberOfSegments,    shiftPercentage,samplesPerWindow );

    //Index=(repmat(1:W,N,1)+repmat((0:(N-1))'*SP,1,W))';
    double[][] index = new double[samplesPerWindow+1][numberOfSegments+1];

    for (int x = 1;  x < samplesPerWindow+1; x++ )
    {
        for (int y = 1 ; y < numberOfSegments + 1; y++) //numberOfSegments was 3
        {
             index[x][y] = reprowMatrix[x][y] + repcolMatrix[x][y];
        }
    }

    //hamming window
    double[] hammingWindow = this.HammingWindow(samplesPerWindow);
    double[][] HW = repvector(hammingWindow, numberOfSegments);

    double[][] seg = new double[samplesPerWindow][numberOfSegments];
    for (int y = 1 ; y < numberOfSegments + 1; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < samplesPerWindow+1; x++)
        {
            seg[x-1][y-1] = signal_in[ (int)index[x][y]-1 ] * HW[x-1][y-1]; 
        }
    }
    MatrixAndSegments Matrixseg = new MatrixAndSegments(numberOfSegments,seg);
    return Matrixseg;
}


public int fix(double val) {
    if (val < 0) {
        return (int) Math.ceil(val);
    }
    return (int) Math.floor(val);
}

public double[][] repvector(double[] vec, int replications)
{
    double[][] result = new double[vec.length][replications];

    for (int x = 0; x < vec.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < replications; y++) {
            result[x][y] = vec[x];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public double[][] reprowtrans(int end, int replications)
{
    double[][] result = new double[end +1][replications+1];

    for (int x = 1; x <= end; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= replications; y++) {
            result[x][y] = x ;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public double[][] repcoltrans(int end, double multiplier, int replications)
{
    double[][] result = new double[replications+1][end+1];

    for (int x = 1; x <= replications; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= end ; y++) {
            result[x][y] = (y-1)*multiplier;
        }
    }  
    return result;
}

public double[] HammingWindow(int size)
{
    double[] window = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        window[i] =  0.54-0.46 * (Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * i / (size-1)));
    }
    return window;
}
```

Comment: This question is about programming rather than signal processing techniques and would be better suited to Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 5):

"Porting" Matlab code statement by statement to Java is a bad approach.

Data is rarely manipulated in Matlab using loops and addressing individual elements (because the Matlab interpreter/VM is rather slow), but rather through calls to block processing functions (which have been carefully written and optimized). This leads to a very idiosyncratic programming style in which `repmat`, `reshape`, `find`, fancy indexing et al. are used to do operations which would be much more naturally expressed through Java loops.

For example, to multiply each column of a matrix A by a vector v, you will write in matlab:

```
A = diag(v) * A
```

or

```
A = repmat(v', 1, size(A, 2)) .* A
```

This solution:

```
for i = 1:size(A, 2),
  A(:, i) = A(:, i) .* v';
end;
```

is inefficient.

But it would be terribly foolish to try to do the same thing in Java and invoke a matrix product or to build a matrix with repeated copies of v. Instead, just do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    a[i][j] *= v[i]
  }
}
```

I suggest you to try to understand **what** this matlab function is actually doing, instead of focusing on **how** it is doing it, and reimplement it from scratch in Java, forgetting all the matlab implementation except the specifications given in the comments. Half of the code you have written is useless, indeed. Actually, it seems to me that this function wouldn't be needed at all, and what it does could be efficiently integrated in the caller's code.